# Count open GWT request

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm trying to write some automatic tests for web application written in GWT. I have problem that many elements on page are loaded/reloaded dynamically using RPC requests. So in my tests I have to write a lot of waiting code for each of this elements and it is very annoying.

Do you have idea how to solve this problem in general? 
I was thinking about counter which will count number of opened RPC requests, but don't know how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to intercept all rpc request is at 
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RpcRequestBuilder.html

You will have to register a builder that extends that one in your gwt.xml file to track what's happening

look also at 
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html

I didn't look further, but the answer to your question is 100% there, I did the same with the request factory mechanism, and I think I did it with rpc a few years ago

Comment: I succeed with adding my own RpcRequestBuilder to single RPC service and indeed it counts request. But I don't know how to do it in general. I mean, is it possible to to set my implementation of RpcRequestBuilder to all RPC services? I tried with Deferred Binding but it don't work.

Comment: Yes this must be in the gwt.wml file. By default there must be a <replace-with> declaration that points to the default RequestBuilder of GWT, you can override it by redeclaring your <replace-with>  with your implementation

Comment: I went to see the javadoc of RpcRB and it states this:
 * HTTP requests issued by RPC proxy objects may override the protected
 * <code>doXyz</code> methods and pass an instance of the subclass to
 * {@link ServiceDefTarget#setRpcRequestBuilder}.

Comment: Now the interface ServiceDefTarget says:
Cast the object
 * returned from {@link com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT#create(Class)} on a
 * {@link RemoteService} to this interface to initialize the target URL for the
 * remote service.

Comment: (forget my first comment, it's not sure GWT uses GWT.create to create the RpcRB)
This means you have to do a ( (ServiceDefTarget)GWT.create(MyService.class)).setRpcRequestBuilder(yourBuilder)

Comment: After reading GWT source I get to the same conclusion. Thanks you very much for help.